# The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine error in windows server

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, ado.net, asp.net-4.0

I am using a excel reader to read contents from the excel,

```
  string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
                 Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
  System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection ExcelConnection 
                 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString);
```

I'm working in VS2010 on a windows 7 ultimate x64 installation.
it works fine in my local machine when I run with VS. When I upload the website in server I get the following error. What should I do here, I have access to the server. Thanks

```
The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. Error
```

: do I have to install any software in my server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Be aware that there will be different versions dependent on whether you are running on 32 or 64 bit architecture.

The providers can be downloaded here:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: 10 seconds faster ;-). Good that you mentioned the architecture.