# published windows app OLEDB 12 provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, installshield

I am trying to publish a little app which runs fine on the dev machine, but when I install it on a fresh win7 machine with no office installed. When I try parts of the app that rely on access DB I get this error. Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

I have been at this for a couple hours now and not sure what the problem is. I went to Build Configuration Manager and set the Platform to X86 from everything I have been reading everyone says to do this and it should work this hasn't done anything.

I am also using installshield but I don't see any prereqs for access db engine or anything.

Anyone know what I need to do to get this app to work on other windows machines?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine error in windows server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398505/the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine-e). Next time you might try at least doing a basic search here for the error message you're receiving before posting. :-)

Comment: Yea it works when I install that but how can I package that with the program installer? So users don't need to go and download that before installing the app.

Comment: I don't use InstallShield, but you can usually add external installations as prerequisites (dependencies) and bundle them right into your own install, and have them run during your own installation. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875615/installshield-le-spring-2012-cant-find-setup-prerequisites?rq=1) - particularly the second answer, which might help. (But that's a different question than the one you asked here, which is in your last paragraph; that question is a duplicate.)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation where my app needed a specific db provider.  I added it as a prerequisite in InstallShield. Go to Tools / Prerequisite Editor to add a new prereq to your install project.  On the Conditions tab, you will most likely want to make sure that a registry key exists for the provider you want.
Then on the Files to Include tab, add a reference to a local file (or url) for the provider you need.
Not a complete answer, but hopefully gets you going in the right direction.

Comment: I changed it to use jet provider and now it works fine without needing the accessdbengine. Thanks though.